# Beginner headache PHP DOMXPath

Tags: php, xpath, scrape, domxpath

I try to write a simple PHP to scrape a html page.
I don't know why I cannot get the result?
Here is some of my PHP code:

```
//$html , successfuly get the html from "http://m.hkgolden.com/topics.aspx?type=HW" by curl

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('x', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml');

$itemList = $xpath->query('//x:div[contains(@class,"TopicBox_Details")]/a');

var_dump($itemList); // it show --> object(DOMNodeList)#4 (0) { }

foreach ($itemList as $item){
        $this->child_urls[] = $item->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
                }

var_dump($this->child_urls); //it show --> array(0) { }
```

the same xpath query is work in the firefox XPath Checker, but the same query cannot work in PHP. am I did something wrong?
[image: Firefox XPath Checker]

Comment: What is the value of `$this->child_xpath` ?

Comment: '// x:div[contains(@class,"TopicBox_Deta ils")]/a'    anyway, I have just replaced it in the question.

Comment: Namespaces. Namespaces. Namespaces. :) But I'm short on time so I can only leave the note.

Comment: In the PHP code, I have use the registernamespace ,  is it something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the namespace to the `a` element in the XPath as well - namespaces get inherited:

```
//x:div[contains(@class,"TopicBox_Details")]/x:a
```

Comment: Thanks, it seem your answer can help, but i cannot try it now, back to home to reach my computer 1 hour later, i am very beginner, to make such simple x n mistake. Not aware of the namespace prefix.

Comment: I still get this result... how can I debug it?

object(DOMNodeList)#4 (0) { }
array(0) { }

@$dom->loadHTML($html);
if I remove the @, to see the log when loadHTML. it show lots of

[Thu Aug 02 19:50:03 2012] [error] [client XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : script in Entity, line: 911 in /home/jasper/www/lab/test2.php on line 52

is it relevant?